# Car hire in Iceland which allows someone other than the driver to pay?

Tags: car-rentals, payment-cards, iceland

I am planning a trip to Iceland with a few friends at the end of February, and we are looking to hire a couple of cars while out there.

We have a slight issue at the moment though in that the car hire companies that we've looked at require that the driver pay by credit card, and a couple of the people who were planning to be drivers for the week don't actually have credit cards...

I have a credit card, but am unable to drive because of health reasons (and don't currently hold a valid driving license)...

Does anyone know of any car hire companies where I could pay for the car hire with my credit card, but not be a named driver on the hire, and put a couple of other people forward as the drivers for the car that I pay for? Or is there anywhere it's possible for one of the drivers to hire the car, but pay for it with my credit card?

Comment: Contact carrenters.is - This is a company which arranges for individuals to rent their cars and they should have considerably more flexibility than traditional car rental companies. As a matter, they have the shortest rental agreement I have ever seen! Didn't try what you are asking, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @JonathanReez suggesting that someone drives without valid insurance is pretty irresponsible IMO.

Comment: Can you rent the vehicle and register your friends as additional drivers?

Comment: @JonathanReez If it's not your own carelessness, an accident *usually* involves other people ("witnesses"). Driving without insurance can easily ruin you financially.

Comment: @Earthliŋ probably not in Iceland. I'd assume the biggest risk there is running off-road or crashing into a random rock on the road, since the car density is so low. In that case you can simply claim you were the driver.

Comment: @JonathanReez - That is highly unlikely, most people are ensured by their own insurance. Of course, if you buy insurance from the rental agency that is a different issue but most people you drive have insurance which in *most* cases covers temporary vehicles of the same class up to a maximum cost. Mine, for example, will insure me any vehicle up to twice the cost of the one I purposefully bought insurance for.

Comment: @Itai I assume the biggest risk is letting the rental company find out and try and fine you for breaking the contract later on. Otherwise, yes, it's easy to buy your own insurance

Comment: I would much prefer to do things 'legally', in every sense of the word, so will definitely not be going down the route of having someone who is not insured for the car to drive.

Comment: @someone2088 - If it says on the contract, one one driver or only a specific driver you are right. No such wording on the contract from carrenters.is though which is why I suggest it.

Comment: Thanks for the name of that website @Itai- I emailed them a couple of hours ago, and they got back to me almost straight away to say that I can use my card even though I am not going to be a driver. All they require is that the drivers be present with their licenses, and that I be present to authorise my credit card.

Comment: I used ba.com to rent a car for my parents. You get to specify if it is for yourself or not. The rental is through Avis, you just book through the airline. I did book it with a flight, but it should work without one as well. I didn't even need to be there. You'll have to check if they have a pickup location suitable for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My wife and I went to Iceland in June 2015, and though I don't drive a car she does, and we booked a rental with [Reykjavik Rent A Car](http://www.reykjavikrentacar.is).  I went back and dug out the receipt, hoping that I'd made the booking, which would be ideal.

Sadly, my wife made the booking.  But they were brilliant in all regards - they actually persuaded us to accept a *refund* of our pre-paid theft insurance because they felt it was a waste of our money ("*Nobody steals cars here.  We are an island.  Where would you go?"*), there was no hint of a practice that is (apparently) common in the UK, of charging us for every tiny scratch ever made in the history of the vehicle - so I wanted to see if I could recommend them here.

I just rang them and they have no problem at all with the renter not being one of the drivers, as long as the card holder is on the trip (which you say you will be).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have a look into that company later this evening.

Comment: Hope they work out for you; just to be clear, I have no connection with them save as a satisfied customer.  That said, you may find it best to speak to them rather than trying to do your rental on the web, because of your (slightly) special requirements.